# PHP 7.4.33 не видит встроенную функцию get_headers

Tags: php

Столкнулся с такой проблемой

код ниже выдает ошибку:
**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function  get_headers()**

```
<?php
$hs = get_headers("https://www.yandex.ru");
print_r($hs);
?>
```

при этом вот такой код работает:

```
 <?php
 foreach(get_headers("https://www.yandex.ru") as $k=>$v)
 {
    echo "$k => $v\n"; 
 }
 ?>
```

Так и не смог разобраться почему.
Может кто сталкивался с таким "странным" поведением ?

Comment: А если убрать пробелы вокруг `=`? Вот так: `$hs=get_headers(...)`

Comment: В смысле, я подозреваю что у вас там вместо пробела какой-то другой символ. Скорее всего неразрывный пробел.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Вы абсолютно правы. Я посмотрел во вьювере mc. Там реально вместо пробелов коды других символов стоят. Ответьте на вопрос я вам зачту правильный ответ